# Where to and how to use getter and setter method in java?

Tags: java, getter-setter

i am trying to use getter and setter method in this program, but keep failing to compile the  file.

```
class mini4
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{

  String nane ="";
   int Gold = 0;
   int Silver = 0;
   int Bronze = 0;
   int total = 0;


   int totalG = 0;
   int totalS = 0;
   int totalB = 0;
   int sumofall = 0;

   country c1 = new country();


   c1 = setcountryname( "United Kindom");
   c1 = setcountryGold( 27);
   c1 = setcountrySilver( 23);
   c1 = setcountryBronze( 17);
   c1 = setcountryTotal( 67);




   String messagetoprint = "";
   String choosemedals = "";

  int totalGold = calculateG(c1,totalG, Gold);
  int totalSilver = calculateS(c1, totalS, Silver);
  int totalBronze = calculateB(c1,totalB, Bronze);
  sumofall = calculateall(totalGold,totalSilver,totalBronze,sumofall);


   System.out.println("                 G   S   B   Total");
   System.out.println(" Great Britain "+totalGold+"　　" +totalSilver +"　　"+totalBronze +"　　"+ sumofall);


  String which = inputString ("which medal total do you want to know? (Gold, Silver or Bronze)"); 
  w(which,totalGold,totalSilver,totalBronze);


  String again = inputString ("DO you want to see the data again? (Yes or No)"); 
  a(again,totalGold,totalSilver,totalBronze,sumofall);

  String oldnew = inputString ("What do you want to see old or new?"); 
  o(oldnew,Gold,Silver,Bronze,totalGold, totalSilver, totalBronze,total,sumofall);

System.exit(0);
}



 public static int calculateG(country c1,int totalG,int Gold)
 {
    Gold = getcountryGold(c1);
    int G = inputInt(" How many people won a Gold ?");
    totalG = Gold + G;
    return totalG;   
    }


public static int calculateS(country c1, int totalS, int Silver)
{   
    Silver = getcountrySilver(c1);
   int S = inputInt(" How many people won a silver ?");  
    totalS = Silver + S;
    return totalS;
 }

 public static int calculateB(country c1,int totalB, int Bronze)
{
     Bronze = getcountryBronze(c1);
    int B = inputInt(" How many people won a bronz ?");
    totalB = Bronze + B;
    return totalB;
}   

  public static int calculateall(int totalGold,int totalSilver,int totalBronze, int sumofall)
{
    int k = 0;
    k = totalGold + totalSilver + totalBronze;
    sumofall = k;
    return  sumofall;   
   }


public static void w(String which, int totalGold, int totalSilver, int totalBronze)
{
    if (which.equals("Gold") ||which.equals("gold"))
    {
        System.out.println(totalGold);

    }
    else if(which.equals("Silver") || which.equals("silver"))
    {
        System.out.println(totalSilver);
    }
    else if(which.equals("Bronze")  ||which.equals("bronze"))
    {
        System.out.println(totalSilver);
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println(" Can you check spelling?");
        System.exit(0);
    }


}
public static String inputString(String message)
{
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   String answer;

   System.out.println(message);
   answer = scanner.nextLine();

   return answer;
} 

public static void a(String again, int totalGold, int totalSilver, int totalBronze, int sumofall)
{
    if (again.equals("Yes") || again.equals("yes"))
    {
       System.out.println("                 G   S   B   Total");
       System.out.println(" Great Britain "+totalGold+"　　" +totalSilver +"　　"+totalBronze +"　　"+ sumofall);

    }
    else if(again.equals("No") || again.equals("no"))
    {
        System.out.println("This is your choose");
    }

    else 
    {
        System.out.println(" Can you check spelling?");
        System.exit(0);
    }


    }
      public static void o (String oldnew, int Gold, int Silver, int    Bronze,int totalGold, int totalSilver, int totalBronze, int sumofall, int total)
    {
        if (oldnew.equals("Old") || oldnew.equals("old"))
        {
          int tt = Gold+Silver+Bronze;
           System.out.println("                 G   S   B   Total");
           System.out.println(" Great Britain "+Gold+"　　" +Silver    +"　　"+Bronze +"　　"+ tt);

        }
        else if(oldnew.equals("New") || oldnew.equals("new"))
        {
           int newtotal = total-sumofall; 
           int gg = totalGold-Gold;
          int ss = totalSilver-Silver;
           int bb = totalBronze-Bronze;
           System.out.println("                 G   S   B   Total");
          System.out.println(" Great Britain "+gg+"　　" +ss +"　　"+bb +"　　"+ newtotal);
    }

        else 
     {
       System.out.println(" Can you check spelling?");
            System.exit(0);
    }


    }


    public static int inputInt(String message)
   {
        return Integer.parseInt(input(message));
     }




      public static String input(String message)
   {
      Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer;

       System.out.println(message);
       answer = scanner.nextLine();

       return answer;
   }

       public static void print(String message)
    { 
       System.out.println(message);

    }

     public static String getcountryname (country c1)
    {
       return  countryname;
 }    
      public static int getcountryGold (country c1)
      {
        return  countryGold;
   }    
      public static int getcountrySilver ( country c1)
    {
       return  countrySilver;
 }    
 public static int getcountryBronze ( country c1)
{
    return  countryBronze;
     }    


    public static country setcountryname (  String newname)
   {
      countryname = newname;
       return countryname;
    }
     public static country setcountryGold ( int newGold)
     {
    countryGold = newGold;
     return countryGold;
    }   public static country setcountrySilver ( int newSilver)
    {
         countrySilver = newSilver;
        return countrySilver;
      }   public static country setcountryBronze (  int newBronze)
   {
      countryBronze = newBronze;
     return countryBronze;
   }
    public static country setcountryTotal ( int newTotal)
    {
     countryTotal = newTotal;
     return countryTotal;
   }

   } 
class country
{
    String countryname;
    String countryGold;
    String countrySilver;
    String countryBronze;
    String countryTotal;

       }
```

after i compile this it has multiple errors, here i want to ask that is there anything wrong with my getter and setter methods and how can i use a getter and setter method correctly?

Comment: what type of errors do you get ?

Comment: Short answer - your getters and setters are in the wrong class.  They need to be in the same class as the fields they get and set.  However, there are very many other things wrong with this program, and I would honestly recommend you work your way through a basic Java tutorial before you try to go too much further.

Comment: clearly state the problem you are facing. don't give the whole code, give the code snippet where you are getting compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the following:

- Don't make the getter, setter method static
- Generally we don't pass any parameter to the getter methods
- Generally, we don't return anything from the setter methods (if you need, then you can do)

Modify your `Country` class as follows:

```
class Country {

    private String countryname;
    private int countryGold;
    private int countrySilver;
    private int countryBronze;
    private int countryTotal;

    public String getcountryname() {
        return countryname;
    }

    public int getcountryGold() {
        return countryGold;
    }

    public int getcountrySilver() {
        return countrySilver;
    }

    public int getcountryBronze() {
        return countryBronze;
    }

    public int getcountryTotal() {
        return countryTotal;
    }

    public void setcountryname(String newname) {
        this.countryname = newname;
    }

    public void setcountryGold(int newGold) {
        this.countryGold = newGold;
    }

    public void setcountrySilver(int newSilver) {
        this.countrySilver = newSilver;
    }

    public void setcountryBronze(int newBronze) {
        this.countryBronze = newBronze;
    }

    public void setcountryTotal(int newTotal) {
        this.countryTotal = newTotal;
    }

}
```

Instead of keeping an additional field for `countryTotal`, you can write a method as follows to return the `countryTotal`. In that case, you don't need the setter method - `setcountryTotal`.

```
public int getcountryTotal() {
    return countryGold + countrySilver + countryBronze;
}
```

Thanks to @DavidWallace for his comment. I have updated my answer as per his suggestions.

Comment: i agree but i didn't know that `countryTotal` is the summation of the other 3 integer fields. i am updating my answer as per your suggestion.